# How to see when your file has been renamed

Tags: windows

I have made a project that renames files using FTP. Now I want to find out which files have not been renamed. I could find it out by looking up those files using the file structure (It is different after the rename), but I want to know if there is a more easy option, like using the "date modified" from windows. (date modified does only work if the file itself has changed, not the name)

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with file systems, former filenames are not recorded unlike the last modification date, therefore there is no easy way to find it out. You should implement your own mechanism to accomplish this.